# How to configure cisco air-cap2602i-e-k9

Tags: cisco, access-point

I can´t access to Cisco AP by http, I have to configure it. After connect to switch, my router (VyOS) show new IP address
`IP 192.168.1.61  1c:6a:7a:e2:80:63  2020/04/22 10:14:49  MyDHCPServer  AP1c6a.7ae2.8063` 
I cannt ping

```
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.61: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
```

But I can´t access to Cisco AP by `http://192.168.1.61` -> ro response.

Answer (score 1):

The CAP in the model number says that it was shipped from Cisco with the controller based software image.  So you don't configure via a GUI.  You can change the image from the controller to the autonomous image.  You would need a CCO account to download the new image though.

From Cisco:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-2600-series/data_sheet_c78-709514.html
AIR-CAP2602I-x-K9: Dual-band controller-based 802.11a/g/n
AIR-SAP2602I-x-K9: Dual-band autonomous 802.11a/g/n